# Why does DBeaver seem to show sparse results and not all columns when connecting to Redshift via SSO (Azure AD)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-active-directory, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I have been connecting to Redshift in AWS for several weeks now using Azure AD SSO based on the writeup provided by AWS[1](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/federate-amazon-redshift-access-with-microsoft-azure-ad-single-sign-on/). I am using the ODBC driver. I can test my connection in my ODBC data sources and I can connect successfully via DBeaver. But when I query tables, I am getting a ton of NULL values in columns where I know there is data. In fact, I can connect with my redshift master user and see the full data set. When I switch back to SSO, I see only some data in some columns. I notice that many of the columns that have endless null values instead of the expected values are varchar data types. Anyone seen this and have any thoughts as to why this occurs? I am pretty sure this was not happening last week, so I'm also wondering if anything changed in either my setup or AWS under the hood.

Comment: Just found the reason I had to provide the DB group in the DSN... a claim was wrong in Azure AD. So please disregard that part of the question... still seeing large sections of data missing when using SSO vs the internal Redshift users.

Comment: I should clarify when I said 'missing columns' above what I meant was that my select * query of a given table will show the column header and a bunch of null values for that column for all records. The columns arent missing just the data in them.